# VIM yank many things then paste all WITHOUT specifying registers?

Tags: vim

Let's say I have the following:

**new example**

I have noticed that my example drove us another route, so here's a new one:

Input:

This is some text that contains some **special** text. There's no specific pattern. All I would **like to do** is copy all those bold sub-sentences once **and for all to** another file. I don't want to copy, **then paste**, then copy then paste because it takes too **long to keep switching** between the files.

Output:
Special
like to do
and for all to
then paste
long to keep switching

**end**

```
var x = "1";
var y = "a thing";
var something = "more things";
// some comment
var foo = "a lot more things";
```

And I want to move the strings between quotes to another file where I declare them as constants.

Is there a way to yank the first string, yank the second, yank the 3rd, and yank the fourth THEN go to the second file and paste the last four yanks **WITHOUT** having to specify the register each time I yank?

A good output would be the following without having to go back and forth between the yanks and the pastes. Yank everything first then paste once:

```
"1"
"a thing"
"more things"
"a lot more things"
```

Comment: you are not moving `the strings between quotes to another file` but string from BOL till the first `"`....

Comment: It's not too big of a deal once it's in the same place.. In my case, I wanted to assign the strings to constants (for internationalization purposes). So bringing it to the other place and then using visual block mode becomes very easy =)

Comment: Why not just yank those lines and paste in new file, and play in the new buffer, remove `".*`?

Comment: what on earth do you want to copy? the value between quotes or what? pls give example, I am confused

Comment: The `"ayf"` was just an example; I changed it. Yanking the whole line (not to the same register as I had figured out in my answer) would present me with the same issue.

Comment: pls paste an example, based on the input, what text do you want to copy/yank

Comment: Example updated to copy what's between the quotes.

Comment: what I meant is TEXT example, not your vim commands.  tell us what TEXT you want to yank/copy, or, after you paste, what TEXT do you want to have. your vim commands look very awkward, to be honest...

Comment: It's clearly stated that I want to copy the "strings between the quotes". I don't care what text I would get as long as I carry those strings to the other file without having to switch many times. I use vim surround so I usually do `ya"` =)

Comment: because the "yank" are from multi. lines, you want to finally yank the text in 4 lines (with linebreak)? or a concatenated big string? is it so difficult to paste an output example?? it is most straightforward way to show the requirement. You were thinking in one way, but there could be another/better way, so what you should show is the target, the goal, not show the way you are on.. and it's clearly stated "strings between the quotes", the answer below doesn't do it, does it?

Comment: There you go.. Above is my goal :-)

Answer (score 1):

what I would do is, copy/yank all these lines to the new file/buffer, then do:

```
%s/^[^"]*\|[^"]*$//g
```

or

```
'[,']s/^[^"]*\|[^"]*$//g
```

to do the replacement only on just pasted text, in case the new file is not empty.

Comment: How do you copy those lines without having to do so one by one? (thus switching between the files many times - this is the main purpose of the question. Everything else is an example)

Comment: @Abdo i.e. `5Y` copy 5 lines counting from your cursor line.

Comment: I added a comment (line starting with //) on purpose to show that those lines might be spreaded in the file. You could have 100 lines, only 4 having strings and quotes.

Comment: `:g/whatever pattern/y Z` then do `"Zp`   for your example it could be `:g/"/y Z` @Abdo  if you love macro, it could be done too, however you have to handle the line-breaks, `ya"` won't have line breaks. btw, your answer does something different.

Comment: This one is pretty good. I still would like to selectively copy sometimes as I have provided in my answer. In programming, we have a lot of strings on different lines, etc... Picking lines with quotes in them (or some other pattern) doesn't make it much easier once the lines are in the other file because you end up having a lot of false positives.

Comment: @Abdo I am sorry if you think this doesn't solve your problem. but if you picked text and appended to a register, the texts are stick together anyway. When you paste, they are together too...   or maybe I didn't understand your question very well. From what I understood, if I do this, I will do in this way.

Comment: I have updated the example.. I know my answer doesn't give the exact output but it's allowing me to not switch between files many times, which is, I think, the most time consuming thing.

Comment: @Abdo ok, then accept your answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I can only accept it in two days. If there are better way, I'd certainly check them instead =)

Answer (score 0):

The answer came to mind after I had finished writing the question. I have faced this issue many times in the past so it makes sense to share it with others (and for myself).

Obviously, putting each string in a register of its own would require us to pull it back from that register, which we might end up forgetting or losing count of (or even mixing up the order)

To work around this, use a single register but append to it instead.

You can also make use of macros to run this quicker. (`@q` is much faster to type than `"Ay$`)

Here's how you do it:

1. Move cursor to first `"` on the first line and type: `"ay$` in order to overwrite the content of register a
2. Go to second line and create a macro as follows:
   `qq0f""Ay$q`
3. Play the macro on each line which string you want to copy (of course this depends on your code but this works for my example above)
   @q
4. Go to the second file to paste: `"ap`

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot specify a pattern to give the location of every bit of text to yank, then simply record a macro that specifies a register and yanks. It looks like you're yanking only things that are within strings so it could be something like this:

First, clear the "a" register, so that you can append into it:

```
qaq
```

Next, record a macro (into q) that appends all text in the quotes under the cursor into register A, and then appends a newline to get all constants on their own line:

```
qq
"Aya"
:let @a.="\n"<CR>
q
```

Now instead of yanking directly, place the cursor on each string to yank, and run the macro with @q (or @@ after you've ran the macro once already).